# ¿Cómo puedo ver la base de datos de SQLite en un proyecto de Xamarin?

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en xamarin con acceso a base de datos, estoy haciendo usos de JSON para la descarga de archivos, pero mi problema es el siguiente estoy actualmente usando mi móvil para emular la aplicación, no estoy usando el emulador que trae visual studio, pero se me presenta el problema que deseo ver si los datos se insertaron correctamente en la base de datos. pero no puedo hacer esto ya que la base de datos del proyecto no se refleja los cambios, hay alguna forma de consultar la bd de datos que tiene el celular almacenada, o bien en la pc?

(lo que deseo mas que todo es poder abrir la base de datos con sqlitestudio)
gracias

Comment: Dale un vistaso a este link a ver si te sirve: https://javiersuarezruiz.wordpress.com/2017/12/18/xamarin-forms-uso-de-sqlite-multiples-tablas-relaciones-y-operaciones-en-cascada/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando te conectas a Sqllite creamos en nuestro proyecto android de xamarin una clase donde nos da una idea en donde se guarda nuestra base de datos de sqlite:

```
public class PathService : IPathService
{
    public string GetDatabasePath()
    {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        return Path.Combine(path, "Sales.db3");
    }
}
```

- Aquí tenemos la ruta Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal) que 
  se traduce en la siguiente ruta /data/data/[paquete_su_app]/files/en mi caso:

  /data/data/com.companyname.Sales/files/Sales.db3
- Como se ve en el código he llamado a la base de datos Sales.db3

Para llegar ha esa ruta puede usar adb y ejecutar el sgte codigo:

```
adb shell
su
```

Hasta este punto debe considerar que para tener permisos de administrador su celular 
  debe estar rooteado y proseguir con la sgte linea

```
cd /data/data/[paquete]/files/
```

En mi caso cd /data/data/com.companyname.Sales/files/ y luego ejecutando ls podra 
  visualizar el sqllite de su app:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego podrias ejecutar la sgte linea para ver su base de datos en este caso seria:

```
sqlite3 sales.db3
```

También podrías copiar la base de datos de tu celular a la pc usando:

```
adb pull /data/data/com.companyname.Sales/files/Sales.db3  d:\
```

Ya teniendo en tu pc puedes abrirlo con tu editor favorito. Espero ayude.